# Hypothesis to use Differentiation Under the Integral Sign

Tags: calculus

I want to use the Differentiation Under the Integral Sign  in a problem, this rule states that:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) dt =  \int_{a}^{b}  \frac{\partial }{\partial x}  f(x,t) dt  $$

But I can't find in any place the conditions under I can apply this rule.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Well, [Wikipedias measure theoretic statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) gives conditions which are easily translated into more basic terms. You might be missing the right keyword: *Leibniz integral rule*.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $\partial f/\partial x$ be a continuous function of the variables $x, t$ (jointly) on $I \times [a,b]$, where $I$ is some neighborhood of $x$. This version is usually sufficient in practice when dealing only with *proper* integrals. When dealing with improper integrals, the versions of this theorem derived from the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem are much more practical.

Comment: @Anonymous Why does the continuity of the partial is sufficient in proper integrals?

Comment: I'd like to correct my statement above. The hypotheses are that $f$ is continuous and $\partial f/ \partial x$ is continuous. The proofs are in Dieudonné's *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, Section VIII.11.